# For a rack app, how do I make passenger-standalone serve the output of .erb files rather of sending the .erb file itself?

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger, erb, rack

**I have a simple *config.ru* rack app** where I only require and run **[rack-server-pages](https://github.com/migrs/rack-server-pages)** to provide dynamic pages in a quick and convenient way. This *config.ru* app is **served by phusion passenger-standalone** (which uses nginx internally).

*.erb* files are processed and served correctly, except when I explicitely add the .erb extension to a URL (for a .erb file). In that case  **the server will send me the .erb file for download, rather than its output.**  Obviously I would like to avoid that.

To make it clearer:

The file on the server is called ***somefile.erb***

*this works:*

```
www.domain.com/somefile
```

*this sends the .erb file for download* ☹:

```
www.domain.com/somefile.erb
```

**How can I fix this? Is this a problem I should manage at the application level** (rack-server-pages), **or at the web server level** (nginx configuration) ? In both cases I would need some help...

**Update 2:** I think [this rack-server-pages file could be relevant](https://github.com/migrs/rack-server-pages/blob/0de830ef11f58298e0a2be7fe9cb3322a8467081/lib/rack/server_pages.rb)... but it's just a wild guess and I wouldn't know what to change in it..

**Update 1:** Pasting passenger-standalone Nginx configuration file. `Passenger-standalone` uses Nginx internally, but with **different settings** than the system-wide Nginx at `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. The default settings for a passenger-standalone Nginx are regenerated at each passenger-standalone run based on the file at `/usr/share/passenger/templates/standalone/config.erb`. Following is that file:

```
##############################################################
#  Phusion Passenger Standalone uses a template file to
#  generate an Nginx configuration file. The original template
#  file can be found by running the following command:
#
#    ls $(passenger-config about resourcesdir)/templates/standalone/config.erb
#
#  You can create a copy of this template file and customize it
#  to your liking. Just make sure you tell Phusion Passenger Standalone
#  to use your template file by passing the --nginx-config-template
#  parameter.
#
#  *** NOTE ***
#  If you customize the template file, make sure you keep an eye
#  on the original template file and merge any changes.
#  New Phusion Passenger features may require changes to the template
#  file.
##############################################################


master_process on;
worker_processes 1;
daemon on;
error_log '<%= @options[:log_file] %>' <% if @options[:log_level] >= LVL_DEBUG %>info<% end %>;
pid '<%= @options[:pid_file] %>';

<% if Process.euid == 0 %>
    <% if @options[:user] %>
        <%# Run workers as the given user. The master process will always run as root and will be able to bind to any port. %>
        user <%= @options[:user] %> <%= default_group_for(@options[:user]) %>;
    <% else %>
        <%# Prevent running Nginx workers as nobody. %>
        user <%= current_user %> <%= default_group_for(current_user) %>;
    <% end %>
<% end %>

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format debug '[$time_local] $msec  "$request" $status conn=$connection sent=$bytes_sent body_sent=$body_bytes_sent';
    include '<%= PhusionPassenger.resources_dir %>/mime.types';

    <% if @options[:ruby] %>
        passenger_ruby <%= @options[:ruby] %>;
    <% else %>
        passenger_ruby <%= PlatformInfo.ruby_command %>;
    <% end %>
    <% if @options[:nodejs] %>
        passenger_nodejs <%= @options[:nodejs] %>;
    <% end %>
    <% if @options[:python] %>
        passenger_python <%= @options[:python] %>;
    <% end %>

    passenger_root '<%= PhusionPassenger.install_spec %>';
    passenger_abort_on_startup_error on;
    passenger_ctl cleanup_pidfiles <%= serialize_strset("#{@working_dir}/temp_dir_toucher.pid") %>;
    passenger_ctl integration_mode standalone;
    passenger_ctl standalone_engine nginx;
    passenger_user_switching off;

    <%= nginx_option :passenger_log_level, :log_level %>
    <%= nginx_option :passenger_max_pool_size, :max_pool_size %>
    <%= nginx_option :passenger_min_instances, :min_instances %>
    <%= nginx_option :passenger_pool_idle_time, :pool_idle_time %>
    <%= nginx_option :passenger_max_preloader_idle_time, :max_preloader_idle_time %>
    <%= nginx_option :passenger_turbocaching, :turbocaching %>
    <% if @options[:user] %>
        passenger_user <%= @options[:user] %>;
        passenger_default_user <%= @options[:user] %>;
        passenger_analytics_log_user <%= @options[:user] %>;
    <% else %>
        passenger_user <%= current_user %>;
        passenger_default_user <%= current_user %>;
        passenger_analytics_log_user <%= current_user %>;
    <% end %>
    <% if @options[:instance_registry_dir] %>passenger_instance_registry_dir '<%= @options[:instance_registry_dir] %>';<% end %>
    <% if @options[:data_buffer_dir] %>passenger_data_buffer_dir '<%= @options[:data_buffer_dir] %>';<% end %>
    <% if @options[:rolling_restarts] %>passenger_rolling_restarts on;<% end %>
    <% if @options[:resist_deployment_errors] %>passenger_resist_deployment_errors on;<% end %>
    <% if !@options[:load_shell_envvars] %>passenger_load_shell_envvars off;<% end %>

    <% if !@options[:friendly_error_pages].nil? -%>
        passenger_friendly_error_pages <%= boolean_config_value(@options[:friendly_error_pages]) %>;
    <% end %>

    <% if @options[:union_station_gateway_address] %>
        union_station_gateway_address <%= @options[:union_station_gateway_address] %>;
    <% end %>
    <% if @options[:union_station_gateway_port] %>
        union_station_gateway_port <%= @options[:union_station_gateway_port] %>;
    <% end %>
    <% if @options[:union_station_gateway_cert] %>
        union_station_gateway_cert -;
    <% end %>

    <% @options[:ctls].each do |ctl| %>
        passenger_ctl '<%= ctl.split("=", 2)[0] %>' '<%= ctl.split("=", 2)[1] %>';
    <% end %>

    default_type application/octet-stream;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    client_max_body_size 1024m;
    access_log off;
    keepalive_timeout 60;
    underscores_in_headers on;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 3;
    gzip_min_length 150;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/json text/javascript
        application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json
        application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf
        application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml text/xml;

    <% if @app_finder.multi_mode? %>
        # Default server entry for mass deployment mode.
        server {
            <% if @options[:ssl] %>
                <% if @options[:ssl_port] %>
                    listen <%= nginx_listen_address %>;
                    listen <%= nginx_listen_address_with_ssl_port %> ssl;
                                                                                               <% else %>
                    listen <%= nginx_listen_address %> ssl;
                <% end %>
            <% else %>
                listen <%= nginx_listen_address %>;
            <% end %>
            root '<%= PhusionPassenger.resources_dir %>/standalone_default_root';
        }
    <% end %>

    <% for app in @apps %>
    server {
        <% if app[:ssl] %>
            <% if app[:ssl_port] %>
                listen <%= nginx_listen_address(app) %>;
                listen <%= nginx_listen_address_with_ssl_port(app) %> ssl;
            <% else %>
                listen <%= nginx_listen_address(app) %> ssl;
            <% end %>
        <% else %>
            listen <%= nginx_listen_address(app) %>;
        <% end %>
        server_name <%= app[:server_names].join(' ') %>;
        <% if app[:static_files_dir] %>
            root '<%= app[:static_files_dir] %>';
        <% else %>
            root '<%= app[:root] %>/public';
        <% end %>
        passenger_app_root '<%= app[:root] %>';
        passenger_enabled on;
        passenger_app_env <%= app[:environment] %>;
        passenger_spawn_method <%= app[:spawn_method] %>;
        <% if app[:app_type] %>passenger_app_type <%= app[:app_type] %>;<% end %>
        <% if app[:startup_file] %>passenger_startup_file <%= app[:startup_file] %>;<% end %>
        <% if app[:concurrency_model] && app[:concurrency_model] != DEFAULT_CONCURRENCY_MODEL %>passenger_concurrency_model <%= app[:concurrency_model] %>;<% end %>
        <% if app[:thread_count] && app[:thread_count] != DEFAULT_APP_THREAD_COUNT %>passenger_thread_count <%= app[:thread_count] %>;<% end %>
        <% if app[:min_instances] %>passenger_min_instances <%= app[:min_instances] %>;<% end %>
        <% if app[:restart_dir] %>passenger_restart_dir '<%= app[:restart_dir] %>';<% end %>
        <% if app[:sticky_sessions] %>passenger_sticky_sessions on;<% end %>
        <% if app[:sticky_sessions_cookie_name] %>passenger_sticky_sessions_cookie_name '<%= app[:sticky_sessions_cookie_name] %>';<% end %>
        <% if app[:vary_turbocache_by_cookie] %>passenger_vary_turbocache_by_cookie '<%= app[:vary_turbocache_by_cookie] %>';<% end %>
        <% if app[:union_station_key] %>
            union_station_support on;
            union_station_key <%= app[:union_station_key] %>;
        <% end %>
        <% if app[:ssl] %>
            ssl_certificate <%= app[:ssl_certificate] %>;
            ssl_certificate_key <%= app[:ssl_certificate_key] %>;
        <% end %>
        <% if @options[:meteor_app_settings] %>
          passenger_meteor_app_settings <%= @options[:meteor_app_settings] %>;
        <% end %>

        <% app[:envvars].each_pair do |name, value| %>
            passenger_env_var '<%= name %>' '<%= value %>';
        <% end %>

        # Rails asset pipeline support.
        location ~ "^/assets/.+-([0-9a-f]{32}|[0-9a-f]{64})\..+" {
            error_page 490 = @static_asset;
        error_page 491 = @dynamic_request;
            recursive_error_pages on;

            if (-f $request_filename) {
                return 490;
            }
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                return 491;
            }
        }
        location @static_asset {
            gzip_static on;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control public;
            add_header ETag "";
        }
        location @dynamic_request {
            passenger_enabled on;
        }
    }
    passenger_pre_start <%= listen_url(app) %>;
    <% end %>
```

Comment: Show full server config. How should we know what's wrong and where?

Comment: @AlexeyTen added it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your ERB pages in directory named `public`?

When Passenger handles a request, Nginx will first try and find a matching file in the `public` directory and if it finds one will serve it directly without passing the request to your app, since many web app frameworks use this directory for static files by default (e.g. Rails, Sinatra).

Since Rack Server Pages also [defaults to `public` for its templates](https://github.com/migrs/rack-server-pages#options),  I suspect this is what is happening in your case. When you use the extension Passenger is able to find a matching file and sends it directly back as the response. Without the extension Passenger passes the request to the app which is able to map in onto the file and process it as expected.

Since it looks like Rack Server Pages also uses `views` as a default template directory, the simplest solution is probably to create a directory with this name and move your templates into it. If you have any static files you could leave them in `public` and get the speed benefit of Nginx serving these as well.

If you prefer you could change the `view_path` configuration option and use a different directory altogether.

If you want to change the configuration on the Passenger side, you could look at the [`static_files_dir` option](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/standalone/reference/#--static-files-dir-static_files_dir). You might have to make sure the directory you choose in this case actually exists, even if it is empty.