# NGINX Configuration on Digital Ocean (fallback)

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have configured my local nginx server with this snippet:

```
   location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri /index.html;
    }
```

which is inside `http { server { ... } }`.  I also have an nginx server on Digital Ocean, and I put the above snippet in the same location (...) in the file `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`.  However, those changes are ignored by the server, i.e., the behavior after is the same as the behavior before (and unlike the behavior of the local server).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you reload your nginx after applying configuration changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is necessary to make the change

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

to

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

in two places in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` also.

Answer (score 0):

After every change you make to your nginx files (or to your website) it is important to reload nginx to apply the changes by using the following in the terminal/command line: `sudo nginx -s reload`

You can also run `nginx -t` to test nginx for any conflicts.

You can (and probably should) run them together to make it easier:

```
sudo nginx -t && sudo nginx -s reload
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that, but I still get an error, e.g.,  http://www.knode.io/559 produces a 404 error on nginx at Digital ocean but not at http://localhost:8080.  The intent is to always serve `index.html` and let the client app parse and handle the rest of the URL.

Comment: NOTE: above, it should be `$uri $uri/`

Comment: @epsilon2.7 are you running ruby on rails by any chance? Also, please post your whole nginx conf file and possibly the files from `sites-enabled` & `sites-available`. Feel free to put placeholder domain names and IP addresses to protect your privacy.

Comment: Not running rails -- Using `nginx` to serve an Elm app.  It consists of two files, `index.html` and `Main.js`.  I'll post the `nginx` files as soon as I figure out a way to do so.  They are two big for the comments.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: Here are links to the nginx files:

http://noteimages.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/nginx.conf
http://noteimages.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/sites-enabled-default
http://noteimages.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/sites-available-default

Comment: If you're using Let's Encrypt, please take a look at [the answer to my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343190/nginx-with-lets-encrypt-welcome-to-nginx-instead-of-rails-app), I think it will help you if you are.